# connection between node.js and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backend

I watch video on Youtube "how to create registration page" in this video

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/registartion", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTropology: true
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log(`connection successful`);
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log(`no connection`)
})
```

they right this code and connect with MongoDB compass and in terminal return "connection successful" but when I try this code it is not connected with mongo compass and in terminal return "no connection " please help me

[image: 1]

Comment: Please provide your MongoDB is running. Provide your os so I can provide a solution.
Also, share the error code with more details

Comment: Also, can you post the result of `console.log(e)`?

Comment: my mongo connection code is present in "conn" and then i import this file "require ("./db/conn")" and this is connect properly but it is not work then i delete conn file and mondo connection code write inside the main app.js file then its work